# Trazer perguntas do SO para o SOpt?

Tags: debate

Muitas vezes me deparo com dúvidas que ao pesquisar encontro reposta(s) no SO.

Sei que é muito comum trazerem essas perguntas pra comunidade SOpt, mas oque devo referenciar?

Imagino que não deva ser algo obrigatório, pois pode ser um usuário que nem sabe da existência dessa pergunta lá. Mas supondo que tenho conhecimento da questão no SO referencio ela por um link na própria questão no SOpt? Ou em um comentário?

Ou ainda, se encontrei no SOpt, mas sei que existe uma boa resposta no SO, seria interessante colocar um cometário com o link do SO para a questão?

Comment: Sim, qualquer referência (que tenha qualidade) é bem-vinda. Se você está fazendo a pergunta e sabe da existência de uma semelhante no SO, você pode linkar na própria pergunta e explicar o porquê das soluções que foram apresentadas lá não resolveram seu problema. Já, se você está respondendo, um comentário com o link já é suficiente (algo como "*Existe uma discussão sobre isso [aqui](#)*"). Eu fiz algo parecido em uma resposta, [veja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202625/como-identificar-se-uma-requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-utiliza-https/202627#comment415170_202627).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não vejo necessidade de referenciar as **perguntas** como copiadas, afinal se é interessante provavelmente alguém fará ela mesmo que nunca tenha usado o SOen, agora "respostas" você sempre deve apontar a referencia, isso não é nem uma obrigação, mas não custa nada apontar a resposta original cujo o autor se esforçou para formular.

Se você acha a pergunta é útil para agregar conteúdo então faça-o, referenciar a original não é necessário, todavia você pode deixar de referencia acaso queira dar a oportunidade de alguém responder e já ter uma "fonte" de pesquisa.

O colega Wallace costuma criar bastante perguntas, sendo elas existentes no SOen ou não, com o intuito de criar uma fonte de pesquisa em português, claro que se você já sabe a resposta no momento de formular a pergunta você pode responder ao mesmo tempo:

> [image: responder]

Então na própria resposta você pode referenciar.

Comment: *"Não vejo necessidade de referenciar as perguntas"* - Se for fazer uma pergunta nova, com seu texto e seu próprio exemplo, eu concordo. Mas se for **traduzir** a pergunta, ou se for utilizar parte dela, acho melhor referenciar.

Comment: @EMBarbosa se for muito especifico e não tiver resposta ou estiver procurando segunda opinião concordo.

Comment: Tenho a sensação que já discutimos isto no meta...

Comment: @JorgeB. sim já falamos disto, mas ele foi um pouco mais especifico, ainda sim se eu encontrar algo marco como dup.